but I [had] hoped that
John had a drinking problem in school. After he graduated, John's friend Darren used his connections to help him get a job at a bank. Darren thought that working at the bank would make John more responsible and help him quit drinking completely. Darren's friend Peter, who works there as a manager, accepted John as a full-time employee.
Scenario #1:
After a month, Peter called Darren and said that John had started drinking again and that trying to help him like that was a waste of time. Later that day, during a conversation with John's parents, Darren told them about his conversation with Peter and, among other things, said the following:
1. I can't stop thinking about John. I knew he had a drinking problem in school, but I had hoped that getting this job would help him stay out of trouble. But maybe his boss, Peter, is right. Maybe he's incorrigible.
Scenario #2:
After a month, Peter called Darren and said that John was a capable employee and that he was thinking of promoting him. Later that day, during a conversation with John's parents, Darren told them about his conversation with Peter and, among other things, said the following:
2. I can't stop admiring John. He's doing much better now. I knew he had a drinking problem in school, but I had hoped that getting this job would help him stay out of trouble. And I was right. Peter, his boss, has been telling me great things about him. He says John is going to make it big one day if he keeps up his pace.
Question:
Would you include the bolded "had" in the above two scenarios? In your opinion, is it optional or required? Thank you.

To me, I had hoped means that I hoped for something in the past, but circumstances have now shown that it isn't going to happen. So it is appropriate in your first scenario but not the second.

To me, "had" is optional in both scenarios. I agree with @KateBunting that it's often used when a past hope doesn't come true, but it's not required and it can be used in other situations. Americans tend not to use perfect tenses very much.
